# Why does system32 have so many different folder names called Drivers/DRIVERS/drivers?

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers

When booting in safe mode the computer will list a bunch of system files it is running, yet the system files are located in differently named Driver folders in System32.

So names of these I saw were:

```
drivers
Drivers
DRIVERS
```

[image]

Is there a reason why they are so different? Is there a reason why there are 3 different drivers folders in different cases in system32?

Comment: Did you look in system32 to see what folders are **actually** there? My Windows 7 only has "drivers" ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Interstingly enough, you are right, but then why does booting into safe mode show different names of DRIVERS folder?

Comment: Same goes to System32 and system32

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Why does system32 have so many different folder names called Drivers?

> So names of these I saw were:
>
> drivers
>
> Drivers
>
> DRIVERS

It doesn't make any difference whether the **win32 system** tries to open a file (directory) named "drivers", "Drivers" or "DRIVERS".

- The driver programmers (vendors) presumably chose to use different variants of the directory name when writing their drivers.
- These names come from the `.INF` files that associate drivers with their hardware. Different `.INF` file writers use different variations of the names.
- Win32 subsystems use the case insensitive mode (case preserving but not case sensitive).

This means that applications can select files on the disk even if the supplied name differs in case from the name stored on the disk.

> As part of the requirements for POSIX compliance, the Windows NT File System (NTFS) provides a case-sensitive file and directory naming convention. Even though NTFS and the POSIX subsystem each handle case-sensitivity well, 16-bit Windows-based, MS-DOS-based, OS/2-based, and **Win32-based applications do not**.
>
> In NTFS, you can create unique file names, stored in the same
>   directory, that differ only in case. For example, the following
>   filenames can coexist in one directory on an NTFS volume:
>
> ```
> CASE.TXT
> case.txt
> case.TXT
> ```
>
> However, **if you attempt to open one of these files in a Win32
>   application**, such as Notepad, **you would only have access to one of the
>   files**, regardless of the case of the filename you type in the Open
>   File dialog box.

...

> NTFS supports two slightly different modes of operation that can be selected by the subsystem of the application interacting with NTFS. The first is fully case sensitive and demands that file names supplied by the application match the names stored on disk including case if the file on disk is to be selected. **The second mode of operation is case preserving but not case sensitive. This means that applications can select files on the disk even if the supplied name differs in case from the name stored on the disk.** Note that both modes preserve the case used to create the files. The difference in behavior noted here applies only when an application needs to locate an existing file. POSIX takes advantage of the full case sensitive mode, while MS-DOS, WOW, and **Win32 subsystems use the case insensitive mode**.

Source [Filenames are Case Sensitive on NTFS Volumes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100625)

Comment: There is a followup question: Why are these directories referred to by these different names? The answer: These names come from the .INF files that associate drivers with their hardware. Different .INF file writers use different variations of the names. Functionally it's not a problem, but they certainly could be more consistent about it. (Just fyi: "folders" are an artifact of Explorer; to the file system, they are directories.)

Comment: @JamieHanrahan already covered in my answer ... "The driver programmers (vendors) presumably chose to use different variants of the directory name when writing their drivers."

Comment: Sure, but now the OP knows _where_ those different variants are written. :)

Answer (score 1):

On windows, it does not matter how you spell a folder. C:\temp is the same as c:\Temp, and even c:\TEMP. Of course, also C:\tEmP will work and C:\teMP too.

Yes, folders are case-insensitive.

When a driver installs itself, it is up to the driver how it places itself into your system32/drivers folder. Windows native drivers commonly will install into DRIVERS, but the rest is up to the driver. A driver installs to %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers, where both System32 and Drivers is written by the driver itself. You can notice that the system32 is also sometimes written as system32 and System32 and could also be written as SYSTEM32.

Comment: So if it the directory it goes in to stays the same, why does it display a different name? Say if someone wrote a driver that had driver written as DrIVer/foo.sys, if foo.sys is written anyways to driver/, then why would it still show up as DrIVer/ on the screen?

Comment: @cyberwebpoweruser: see the comment on the previous answer: http://superuser.com/questions/877257/why-does-system32-have-so-many-different-folder-names-called-driver#comment1168590_877268

Comment: @cyberwebpoweruser The actual driver file might be driver/foo.sys, but there's another file that tells Windows to load a driver from DrIVer/foo.sys, and so that's where it looks (and finds driver/foo.sys) but prints DrIVer/foo.sys anyway.